# Error occurs when the field is empty during a multiply expression

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I came accross a strange problem:
When I use a simple expression like:

```
=iif(Fields!Length.Value = "", "empty", Fields!Length.Value)
```

then everything works, and I get my value, or the word "empty" in my report.

[image]

If I would change my expression to a sum of 2 times the length, then my "empty" would still appear.

```
=iif(Fields!Length.Value = "", "empty", (Fields!Length.Value + Fields!Length.Value))
```

[image]

But when I multiply, then my "empty" goes to #Error,  While the rest of the data works fine...

```
=iif(Fields!Length.Value = "", "empty", (Fields!Length.Value * Fields!Length.Value))
```

[image]

Any idea? I find this behavior very, very weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that IIF evaluates both the true and false results everytime, even if the false result won't be used in the final output. So it's trying to do

```
'' * ''
```

when you value is an empty string.

You can fix this by using VAL which will return the numeric value of the string first, like this.

```
=IIF(Fields!Length.Value = "", "empty", (VAL(Fields!Length.Value) * VAL(Fields!Length.Value)))
```

Comment: This works like a sharm thanks!
I've tried VAL, but for the whole formula instead of 2 times separate.